# Randomly shuffle a grid of values?

Tags: r, random, vector, shuffle

What tools are available to randomly shuffle a grid of values in R?

I know of none.  The values can't be changed, I just need their order reshuffled.  Indeed, the grid could be represented as a linear data set, in which case the question becomes: how do I randomly reshuffle a vector of values?

Comment: Did you try to google "randomly reshuffle a vector of values in R"?  It gives plenty of relevant hits...

Comment: This has been answered [here][1] (using the sample(x) function).


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081498/the-correct-approach-of-randomly-re-ordering-a-matrix-in-r

Comment: Duplicate of [Randomly re-order (shuffle) rows of a matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081498/the-correct-approach-of-randomly-re-ordering-a-matrix-in-r)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`sample(x)`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sample.html) gives a random permutation of `x`.

For example:

```
> sample(c(1,3,5,7,9))
[1] 5 7 1 3 9
```